# How to obtain and display user name?

Tags: powershell

I have developed a script where it opens several docs, website, etc., but I would like to have it more personalized for the person opening the document, I have a greeting at the beginning of the script (`Write-Host "Good Day GWFO Analyst" $analyst_name`), but I would like for it to display the person name. Can anyone provide me steps on how to do this? I looked up several docs, but they sometimes all point to other program, tools, etc., and we are in a closed environment at work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, this question seems opinion-based, and since you provided little effort, your question is too broad to be solved adequately.

Comment: `Write-Host "Good Day GWFO Analyst" $env:USERNAME`

Comment: try with whoami

Answer (score 2):

since you asked for direction that's what i'll provide.

You can do something as simple as whoami with a split method or the env username.. both should pull the same info

```
(whoami).split("\")[1]
$env:username
```

This will display the current username

You can also use wmi to get the user account, if it has more details, you can pull those... this will pull the Person's name... if it's known to the system

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_useraccount | where {$_.caption -eq (whoami)} | select -Expand Fullname
```

Is an option, I recommend using

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_useraccount | select *
```

to see what comes out, and how you can get what you want from it. Also if you're not admin, it may show less or more info... just requires you to do some work.

Comment: Thank you so much this is an awesome help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: `([adsi]"WinNT://$env:userdomain/$env:username,user").fullname` Gives you their display name which seems to be faster than most things I have tried. Everything else hangs for quite some time.

Comment: If you got the answer here, please select the answer as accepted. But either way stack over flow is mostly for improving or solving a coding issue. Not just writing code, so people will downvote when you just ask a question. Glad I helped.